# Trigger with last inserted id from another table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

i actually try to write a trigger which will be automatically created the user's cart.
My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    Users_Id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(70),
    Surname varchar(70),
    Phone varchar(12),
    Login varchar(20),
    Password varchar(20),
    Address varchar(255),
    Primary Key(Users_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Cart (
    Cart_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Users_id int,
    Total_price double,
    Primary Key(Cart_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Users_id) REFERENCES USERS(Users_Id)
);
```

I wrote the after insert trigger but I don't know how to add the last user id in the cart.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_user 
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO cart (users_id, total_price)
  VALUES (106, 1);
```

My question is how to pass the added user id in that trigger instead of 106

Comment: *how to pass the added user id in that trigger instead of 106* `NEW.Users_Id`

Comment: This seems conceptually wrong in that you only create a cart by adding a user